# Django: a class based view with mixins and dispatch method

Tags: python, django, django-views, mixins

Normally, I use a `dispatch` method of a class based view to set some initial variables or add some logic based on user's permissions.

For example,

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

class GenerateReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'reporting/reporting_form.html'
    form_class = ReportForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.fields['report_type'].choices = [
                choice for choice in form.fields['report_type'].choices
                if choice[0] != INVOICE_REPORT
            ]
        return form
```

It works as expected: when an anonymous user visits a pages, the `dispatch` method of [LoginRequiredMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py#L45) is called, and then redirects the user to the login page.

But if I want to add some permissions for this view or set some initial variables, for example,

```
class GenerateReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (
            self.request.user.is_superuser or
            self.request.user.is_manager
        ):
            raise Http404
        return super(GenerateReportView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

in some cases it doesn't work, because `dispatch` methods of the mixins, that the view inherits, haven't been called yet. So, for example, to be able to ask for user's permissions, I have to repeat the validation from `LoginRequiredMixin`:

```
class GenerateReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and not (
            self.request.user.is_superuser or
            self.request.user.is_manager
        ):
            raise Http404
        return super(GenerateReportView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

This example is simple, but sometimes there are some more complicated logic in a mixin: it checks for permissions, makes some calculations and stores it in a class attribute, etc.

For now I solve it by copying some code from the mixin (like in the example above) or by copying the code from the `dispatch` method of the view to another mixin and inheriting it after the first one to execute them in order (which is not that pretty, because this new mixin is used only by one view).

Is there any proper way so solve these kind of problems?

Comment: first call ``super(GenerateReportView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)``. then do the rest of the job inside the dispatch you are overriding

Comment: @MihaiZamfir It won't work because, for example, ``LoginRequiredMixin`` returns a ``HttpResponseRedirect`` object, so if we store it in a variable, it won't make a redirect to the login view until we return this variable at the end of ``dispatch`` method.

Comment: but you can check if the response is a redirect, then continue with the dispatch

Comment: The issue is that upstream processing of mixins may result in valid redirect. E.g. There is inheritance hierarchy like (LoginRequiredMixin, CustomViewWhichRedirectsSometimes), now, if dispatch of login required returns redirect, we need to somehow judge if it's because user is not authorized or if perfectly expected redirect from CustomViewWhichRedirectsSometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write custom class, which check all permissions

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from braces.views import AccessMixin

class SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin(AccessMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return self.handle_no_permission(request)
        if self.user_has_permissions(request):
            return super(SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(
                request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise Http404 #or return self.handle_no_permission

    def user_has_permissions(self, request):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_manager

# a bit simplyfied, but with the same redirect for anonymous and logged users
# without permissions


class SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin(AccessMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user_has_permissions(request):
            return super(SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(
                request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.handle_no_permission(request)

    def user_has_permissions(self, request):
        return request.user.is_authenticated() and (self.request.user.is_superuser
                                                    or self.request.user.is_manager)


class GenerateReportView(SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin, FormView):
#Remove next two lines, don't need it
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #or put some logic here
        return super(GenerateReportView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And implementation of class GenerateReportView(SuperOrManagerPermissionsMixin, FormView) does not require overriding dispatch method

If you use multiple inheritance and one of the parent classes need some improvement, it's good to improve it first. It keeps code cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

For the example you gave, I would use `UserPassesTestMixin` from [django-braces](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/v1.4.0/).

```
class GenerateReportView(UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    def test_func(self, user):
        return user.is_superuser or user.is_manager
```

If that isn't suitable for your more complicated logic, then creating a separate mixin sounds like an OK approach, as it encapsulates the complicated logic nicely.

**EDIT**
As of django 1.9, the UserPassesTestMixin is now included in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin

Answer (score 4):

this is an old post but other people might come across so here is my proposed solution.

When you say

> "[...]I want to add some permissions for this view or *set some
>   initial variables*, for example[...]"

Instead of setting those initial variables in the dispatch method of your view, you could write a separated method for setting up those variables, and then call that method in your get (and post if needed) method. They are called after dispatch, so setting up your initial variables wont clash with the dispatch in your mixins.
So override the method

```
def set_initial_variables():
    self.hey = something
    return 

def get(blablabla):
    self.set_initial_variables()
    return super(blabla, self).get(blabla)
```

This probably is cleaner than copying and pasting the code of your mixin in your view's dispatch.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with Django [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/)  mixin or [@user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/) decorator.

**Example of UserPassesTestMixin**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin


class SuperUserOrManagerRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        if self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_manager:
            return True

        return False


class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuperUserOrManagerRequiredMixin, View):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you override the `dispatch`, like you've noticed, your `LoginRequiredMixin` would stop working. While you could add a check to see if the user is authenticated, just that check wouldn't be enough to handle the redirects too.

Just like mentioned in two other answers, I also prefer to use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) with a `test_func()` method containing the logic. The reason I'm writing this answer is to show it can be used

- together with the LoginRequiredMixin
- for more complex cases (with try/excepts for example)

Here's what I'd do in your case

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class GenerateReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'reporting/reporting_form.html'
    form_class = ReportForm

    def test_func(self):
        if not (
            self.request.user.is_superuser or
            self.request.user.is_manager
        ):
            return False
        try:
            # some logic
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

---

Notice the usage of `LoginRequiredMixin` before `UserPassesTestMixin`. The order is relevant. It means that it'll check if the user is authenticated first, before checking the `test_func()`. If the user is not authenticated, then will be redirected to the login page.

Also, I like how you use the `if not (...)`, which was adapted to

```
if not (...):
    return False
```

In addition to that, since you're looking for some more logic, you can do that with a `try/except` block (which could even call another function(s))

```
try:
    # some logic
    return True
except:
    return False
```

`return True` is to say that the user has then permissions to access the view, whereas `return False` will give to the user a 403 status code.