# What should I override in a FormView to insert my permissions checking?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Of its available methods, which is the ideal place to place permission checking? If `get()`, should it also be in the `post()`?

The code lives in its own permissions.py and looks like this:

```
def has_perm_or_is_owner(user_object,
                          permission,
                          instance=None):
    if instance is not None:
        if user_object == instance.user:
            return True
    return user_object.has_perm(
        permission
    )
```

It checks whether the request.user is the rightful owner of the form instance. This particular form should not be viewable to anyone else.

The code I am trying to find a place to insert within the CBV, is here:

```
can_edit = has_perm_or_is_owner(
            self.request.user,
            'profile.fill_form',
            instance=obj,
        )
        if not can_edit:
            raise Http404
```

This is usually an easy choice with, say, an UpdateView, as I'll just stick it inside the `get_object()`. With FormViews, this is a bit more ambiguous. Thoughts?

edit: if you have comments pertaining to what the actual best practice would be in cases of CBV permissions, I would love to hear it.

Comment: If you want to check the permission in both `get` and `post` method, you could do it in [`dispatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method.

Comment: @AKS, I was looking into overriding the dispatch method as you suggested when I found a comment suggesting the use of the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin). What do you think of this method?  
edit: the dispatch-related post I was looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824181/django-a-class-based-view-with-mixins-and-dispatch-method