# Execute code in dispatch method with LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: python, django

```
class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    # Variant 1
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # Do some other checks after making sure the user is logged in
        # This does not work because the LoginRequiredMixin
        # will be executed after calling the super method

        return super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    # Variant 2
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

        # Do some other checks after making sure the user is logged in
        # This does not work because this part will be also executed
        # if the user is not logged in

        return response
```

How can I execute code in the dispatch method after the user is logged in using a Class Based View with the LoginRequiredMixin?

Comment: What do you mean, "after the user is logged in"? Do you mean *immediately subsequent* to logging in? This view isn't the thing that is doing the logging in though, this just asserts that the user is already logged in. To do something straight after logging in, you should write a signal handler for the [`user_logged_in` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in).

Comment: @DanielRoseman This view requires a logged in user. I have a extra login page which has nothing to do with this view. After making sure the user is logged in, I want to do another permission check in the dispatch method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) with a `test_func()` method containing your logic. You don't need to override `dispatch` at all.

```
class HomeView(UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):
    ...
    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_authenticated and my_custom_logic(self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use your second variant and then check if the user is authenticated yourself:

```
# Variant 2
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Your code here

    return response
```

Note: You should not need to override the `dispatch` method to achieve that, but since it was your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this solution, however, the `if request.user.is_authenticated` would be double. This code is in the LoginRequiredMixin. I will use the UserPassesTestMixin.

Comment: Yes, you should not need to check it twice. You should go with Daniel Roseman answer. Just added this answer since the question was: `Execute code in dispatch method...`. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) with a `test_func()` method containing the logic.

You can use the `LoginRequiredMixin` before `UserPassesTestMixin`.

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class HomeView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):

    def test_func(self):
        try:
            # some logic
            return True
        except:
            return False
```

The order is relevant. It'll check first if the user is authenticated, before considering the `test_func()`. [More about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906258/5675325).